# Laravel 5 - updating child table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a database design like so:
[image: Design]

A contact_report can have many contact_report_actions.  My tables may look something like this

```
Project

id    | data         | 
----------------------
1     | something    | 
----------------------

document

id    | data         | project_id
---------------------------------
1     | something    | 1
---------------------------------

document_actions

action         | deliveryDate  | documentID
--------------------------------------------
Walk dog       | 01/01/2016    | 1
--------------------------------------------
Wash clothes   | 08/02/2016    | 1
--------------------------------------------
Party          | 09/02/2016    | 1
--------------------------------------------
```

I am having a few issues updating the contact_report_actions table.  At the moment I am trying something like this:

```php
public function update(Project $project)
{
    $project->contactReportDoc->discussionPoints = Input::get('discussionPoints');

    $actions = Input::get('actionInput');

    foreach($actions as $action => $input) {
        $contactReportActionsDoc = ContactReportActionsDoc::firstOrNew(['action' => $input["action"]]);
        $contactReportActionsDoc->action = $input["action"];
        $contactReportActionsDoc->responsibility = $input["responsibility"];
        $contactReportActionsDoc->save();
    }

    $project->contactReportDoc->update();
    $projectId = $project->id;

    $contactReportDoc = ContactReportDoc::where('projectId', '=', $projectId)->first();

    return Redirect::route('projects.contactReportDoc.edit', compact('project', 'contactReportDoc'));
}
```

`$actions` are the input of the user.  What I have to do is see if the action already exists and if so, update it.  Otherwise I need to create a new row for a new action.  I cant seem to pass it the actions array and call the update on this because it complains that function update does not exist.  How can I update rows within my `contact_report_actions` table?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of relationship between the projects and contact_report. As I can see in image it is one to many is it ?

Comment: That is correct, although I limit it to one

Comment: Try by replacing the for loop code as below:


    `foreach($actions as $action => $input) {

 $contactReportActionsDoc = new ContactReportActionsDoc();

        if ($input['action']) {

         $contactReportActionsDoc = ContactReportActionsDoc::where('action','=',$input["action"])->first();
        }     

        $contactReportActionsDoc->action = $input["action"];
        $contactReportActionsDoc->responsibility = $input["responsibility"];
        $contactReportActionsDoc->save();
    }`

Comment: It seems to save the last input as the first.